# Get Splash Screen defined in the Winforms project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

It is possible to get the Splash Screen during the load, if it is defined in the project properties?
[image]

During the `Form1_Load` event I want to be able to put different messages on the splash screen setting a label it has for that purpose, so the user can see the progress of the load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. You can access the Splash Screen with this:

```vb
Private ss As SplashScreen1 = My.Application.SplashScreen
```

But, in order to set its properties, as they are in a different execution thread, you will need a Delegate. This method is an example of how to set a label called `CurrentMessage`:

```vb
Private Sub SetSplashScreenMsg(text As String)
    If ss.InvokeRequired() Then
        ss.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf SetSplashScreenMsg), text)
    Else
        ss.CurrentMessage.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
```